# Naming array items 0001, 0002 etc

Tags: c#, algorithm

I was trying to think an algorithm for naming an array. For example, it will have 1000 items. The names will be 0000, 0001, 0002 etc.

Which is better - the names to be strings or integers?

If int => how can I add the zeros in front?

If strings => wouldn't it be too complicated to find the last digit - increment it, and if it's 9 go to the previous digit. And it's a lot of parsing.

Which do you think is better?

Comment: Why do you want `0`s in front?

Comment: What do you mean by naming an array ?

Comment: What is your actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: can you clarify? the names are just representational and can be presented to the user in anyway you want. `int`s are way better.

Comment: Isn't the index of the elements enough of a unique identifier? Of course you can format it as you want but what's the reason?

Comment: @V4Vendetta Naming an array items.

Comment: What do you mean by "naming an array"? If you have an array, you just access elements by index, e.g. for a 1000 element array your indices are 0 to 999 inclusive.

Comment: @MAK I thought giving name to an array items. For example, the array will have filenames with names 0001, 0002 etc.

Comment: @user966638 - Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I have a string array which contains names of files. I want the filenames to be numbers with 4 digits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use integers, but when you display things, convert it to a string and add the leading zeros.

Comment: Do you mean like: go from 0 to 999. If the number has less then 4 length then add zero in front.

Comment: I can't believe it was this easy :)

Comment: Well if you use integers as internal representation then you would have an array with indices 0 to 999. Then when it comes to displaying the index in the array to the user, add 1 to it : displayIndex = index + 1. Then convert displayIndex to a string. If the string has length less than 4, add zeros in front.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better using `int`s and formatting it when you want to display it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
                      .Select(x => x.ToString("0000"));
```

if you already have a list of numeric items:

```
numericItems.Select(x => x.ToString("0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array uses Index's to identify or get a Value stored in ,so i don't know if it's reasonable to name an array ,just find a logic way to work with indexes and it's values into that position .